# Angular 7 karma test with importing external JS modules

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, angular7

I am testing a Angular 7 component which has importing JS modules like:

component.ts

```
import * as classA from '../../classA'; // Imported JS modules
export class component implements OnInit {
  public a = new classA(10); // Instantiate
  ...
}
```

classA.js

```
class classA {
  constructor (a) {
    this.max = a;
    ...
}

if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && typeof module.exports !== 'undefined') {
    module.exports = classA;
}
```

component.spec.ts

```
import * as classA from '../../classA';
```

I am importing classA as what I did in component.ts.

Component.ts is working perfectly but when I am running ng test, it gives an error: `TypeError: classA is not a constructor`

I tried to include it in karma.conf.js like:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    ...
    files: [
      "../app/classA.js"
    ]
  });
};
```

But still get same error. Anyone has any idea how to import JS modules in unit testing?

Answer (score 1):

You use es6 modules import but define commonjs module.
Better use es6 modules as well.

classA.js

```
class classA {
  constructor (a) {
     this.max = a;
    ...
}
export default classA
```

Or use require:

```
 let classA = require('../../classA');
```

Comment: Thanks. But I cannot edit classA.js since we use it in other places. And it works in component.ts. Only karma test is broken. So do you have any other idea to import it properly in component.spec.ts?

Comment: Then use require to get the class, like  let classA = require('../../classA');

Answer (score 1):

I found the way to fix this testing error. In Angular 7, the right way to import JS commonjs module in component.ts is

`import classA from '../../classA';`

with

```
"esModuleInterop": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
```

in tsconfig.json